# How do I select rows that contain any of the selected values in any of the selected columns? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pretty much trying to get all of the rows that contain any of the relevant tags in any of the relevant columns.

Take a look at an example row:

```
[LeadID Leadname    Ratings AvgRating   Address Website Phone   TimesOpen   Category    LeadDescription CurrentStatus]
1   Siena Tuscan Steakhouse 396 4.300   104 S Broadway, Wichita, KS 67202, United States    http://www.sienawichita.com/    +1 316-440-5300 LGBTQ+ friendly2022-05-19 Thursday 5PM–12AM
2022-05-20 Friday 6:30–10AM
2022-05-21 Saturday 7–11AM
2022-05-22 Sunday 7–11AM
2022-05-23 Monday 6:30–10AM
2022-05-24 Tuesday 6:30–10AM
2022-05-25 Wednesday 5PM–10AM
    restaurants Hotel restaurant-bar offering refined Italian plates & many wines in a warm & elegant atmosphere.
```

I don't think you'll need to see it in structured form so I apologize for it being messy.
Everything in [ ] are the column names, and the following are its respective fields.

Here is my query

```
    SELECT LeadID
    FROM cleancopy
    WHERE
        Website OR LeadName OR LeadDescription OR Category 
        IN ('%Event%' OR '%Live%' OR '%Music%' OR '%Venue%');
```

This query is returning all rows *unfiltered*.

I want the query to select all rows that contain any number of the relevant tags "Event", "Live", "Music", "Venue", in any of the column names Website, LeadName, LeadDescription, Category.

So one or all of the tags could be in one or all of the attribute types.

More simply put, I'm trying to filter out any row that doesn't contain any of the keywords I want.

Comment: Unfortunately, `OR` doesn't work the way you intend it to - it needs to connect clauses with Boolean outcomes. Since `Website` will have a tru-ish value, MySQL will consider that a match and stop evaluating. I think you're going to end up with 16 clauses of the form `Website LIKE '%Event%' OR Website LIKE '%Live%' OR...` You might be able to use regular expressions to reduce that to four Clauses.

Comment: Alternately you might be able to concatenate the four columns and then apply regex in a `HAVING` clause and streamline it more.

Comment: Finally, don't ask us to take a look at something, and give us... that. Probably easiest in that case to past in your table definition, rather than an example row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing: "I don't think you'll need to see it in structured form" is a very bad assumption. We DO need this because it makes it much easier to provide a good answer.
Second thing: This is not the kind of data checking SQL is done for. So there is no simple way especially when you really need a list of strings and a like condition. Such complex data handling should better be avoided or done outside SQL and within the application.
Anyway, the shortest way to do what you describe will be to `CONCAT` all columns and then search for your strings using `OR`.

```
SELECT leadid FROM cleancopy WHERE
CONCAT(website,leadname,leaddescription,category) LIKE '%Event%'
OR CONCAT(website,leadname,leaddescription,category) LIKE '%Live%'
OR CONCAT(website,leadname,leaddescription,category) LIKE '%Music%'
OR CONCAT(website,leadname,leaddescription,category) LIKE '%Venue%'
```

Comment: Okay, thank you and I apologize for that assumption, I'm new to using stackoverflow.

If SQL is not an optimal language to answer this kind of question, what do you suggest using for this sort of data checking? 
I'm currently using SQL to filter out a fairly large list of records taken in from a web scraper to generate a specific lead list, but I'm starting to realize its limitations in providing insights like this.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it tells you what you asked for? I think the other question should be asked separately because this is another topic and more people can help you then. For this second topic, more information would be nice which is also easier when you create a new specific question.